# SingleChildScrollView and TabBarView do not work together

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                ...
              ],
            ),
             Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      ...
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                ],
              ),
            ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                     ...
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
           
            
             DefaultTabController(
                  length: 3,
                  initialIndex: 0,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: TabBar(
                            tabs: [
                             ...
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                            child: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                  ...
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Text('Display Tab 2',
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Text('display 3'),
                              )
                            ]))
                      ])),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I defined my body as singlechildscrollview so I thought the page wouldn't overflow. I gathered the elements under it under a column. But it started to overflow according to the height property on the tabBarView. For example, if I want it to spread to the whole device as in the code, it gives overflow after fitting 5 6 elements into the column under the tabbarview. But if I give values ​​like 200, 300, overflow occurs after the second widget I gave to the column. I want to make the whole page Scrollable. Why is it not enough to make the body SingleChildScrollView for this and what should I do?